# is a native_handle_type of pthread_t * guaranteed for libc++ and libstdc++?

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11, winapi, pthreads

Look at this code:

```
#include <pthread.h>
#include <mutex>

int main()
{
    std::mutex mtx;
    pthread_mutex_t *native = mtx.native_handle();
}
```

Do libstdc++ or libc++ guarantee that the `native_handle` of a `std::mutex` is always a `pthread_mutex_t*` pointer? That would be nice because I can adjust the spin count of this `std::mutex` implementation with that.

Windows gives only a `void*` pointer for `native_handle` and I don't know its purpose. If I cast it to a `CRITICAL_SECTION` and call any Windows' own calls on it, I have a crash.

Does Windows return the handle used in the slow path synchronization across the kernel when there is contention?

Comment: No, it's not guaranteed, check cppreference.com. Finding out the purpose of the void pointer in Windows should be easy, just read the sources.

Comment: I didn't ask for C++ in general but for the guarantees of a specific implementation.

Comment: On Windows it can be cast to type `HANDLE`, which is used in win32 api (e.g. in `WaitForSingleObject` to wait for a mutex or any other kernel object to be signaled).

Comment: @wohlstad: For me that absolutely doesn't make sense. Because for both paths you have an atomic variable where someone waiting in the kernel registers itself als being waiting. If you simlpy wait only on the handle you might wait forever of get awakened for someone other having registered and this threads would sleep forever.

Comment: @BonitaMontero I didn't understand what you mean. Maybe you can explain why you need to use the `native_handle` ? In any case you should either use OS specific apis with the native_handle, or use the standard std::mutex methods. I agree using both doesn't make sense.

Comment: I need this APIs under POSIX to adjust the spin-count. I won't use pthread_mutex_t directly because std::mutex is magnitudes more convenient to use.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to future-proof your implementation, you can use overload resolution to dispatch between different native_handle types.

```
#include <mutex>

#ifndef WIN32
# include <pthread.h>

void tune_mutex(pthread_mutex_t* mutex)
{
  // adjust spin-count
}
#endif

void tune_mutex(void*)
{
  // Fallback for unknown types. Do nothing
}

int main()
{
  std::mutex mutex;
  tune_mutex(mutex.native_handle());
}
```

At least for GCC and Clang this should work. Also note that changing the return type would break the existing ABI (even if the standard allows it), so you can be reasonably sure that this won't change anytime soon. And I don't see a reason why it should change. People would want whatever improvements come to one mutex type also be present in the other.

For Windows, there is a note in the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/standard-library/mutex-class-stl?view=msvc-170)

> `native_handle_type` is defined as a `Concurrency::critical_section*` that's cast as `void*`

Comment: Nice, with that Idea I won't have to know if libstdc++'s or libc++'s mutex is implemented as a plain pthread_mutex_t. But for Windows I don't have Concurrency::critical_section if I include <mutex> as well as <Windows.h>.

Comment: @BonitaMontero If I see it correctly, it's defined in the concrt.h header. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/parallel/concrt/reference/critical-section-class?view=msvc-170

Comment: Which, in turn, says that "*A `critical_section` object is not associated with a platform specific native handle for the Windows operating system. The [`native_handle`] method simply returns a reference to the object itself.*"

Answer (score 0):

I guess mutex::lock() and mutex::unlock() arent backed by EnterCriticalSection() and LeaveCriticialSection under Windows.
I wrote this little program:

```
#include <Windows.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <mutex>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    CRITICAL_SECTION cs;
    InitializeCriticalSection( &cs );
    EnterCriticalSection( &cs );
    LeaveCriticalSection( &cs );
    mutex mtx;
    for( size_t i = 100'000'000; i--; )
        mtx.lock(),
        mtx.unlock();
    cout << "finished" << endl;
}
```

With the calls to EnterCriticalSection() and LeaveCriticalSection() I set two breakpoints on the DLL entry points of these functions. And both aren't hit in the loop. So I think std::mutex is implemented with the usual combination of an atomic variable and a binary semaphore under Windows.

I also tried to act on the native_handle() as it would have been a HANDLE by doing a WaitForSingleObject() on it. I immeadiately get a INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE on it, so it's for sure not a HANDLE.

But I thought something more in-depth about spinning: Spinning makes sense when a) the mutex is held only a very short time that spinning might succeed and b) when there's a extremely high locking and unlocking frequency across all cores. I think that's rather a rare case.